# When I try to construct a table with more than two columns I get an error

Tags: tables

I am new to latex and am using a python package called `stargazer` to generate latex code. Whenever I try and make an output with more than 2 columns I get an error.

```
! Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr.
<template> \endtemplate 

l.10 ...column{3}{c}{\textit{Dependent variable:}}'
```

I know that this question is not worded perfectly. I would appreciate any help but would like to avoid being screamed at for posting in a poor format.

Why does this work

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htbp] \centering
  \label{}
\begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{5pt}}lcc}
\\[-1.8ex]\hline
\hline \\[-1.8ex]
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textit{Dependent variable:}} \
\cr \cline{2-3}
\\[-1.8ex] & (1) & (2) \\
\hline \\[-1.8ex]
 Best Random & 0.392$^{***}$ & \\
  & (0.041) & \\
  & & \\
 Worst Random & & 0.518$^{***}$ \\
  & & (0.046) \\
  & & \\
 const & 0.002$^{}$ & 0.004$^{***}$ \\
  & (0.001) & (0.001) \\
  & & \\
\hline \\[-1.8ex]
 Observations & 156.0 & 156.0 \\
 R${2}$ & 0.375 & 0.453 \\
 Adjusted R${2}$ & 0.371 & 0.45 \\
 Residual Std. Error & 0.014(df = 154.0) & 0.013(df = 154.0)  \\
 F Statistic & 92.575$^{***}$ (df = 1.0; 154.0) & 127.778$^{***}$ (df = 1.0; 154.0) \\
\hline
\hline \\[-1.8ex]
\textit{Note:} & \multicolumn{2}{r}{$^{*}$p$<$0.1; $^{**}$p$<$0.05; $^{***}$p$<$0.01} \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end {document}
```

while this does not :

```
\begin{table}[!htbp] \centering
  \label{}
\begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{5pt}}lcc}
\\[-1.8ex]\hline
\hline \\[-1.8ex]
& \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textit{Dependent variable:}} \
\cr \cline{3-4}
\\[-1.8ex] & (1) & (2) & (3) \\
\hline \\[-1.8ex]
 Best Random & 0.392$^{***}$ & & \\
  & (0.041) & & \\
  & & & \\
 Mean Randoms & & & 0.856$^{***}$ \\
  & & & (0.043) \\
  & & & \\
 Worst Random & & 0.518$^{***}$ & \\
  & & (0.046) & \\
  & & & \\
 const & 0.002$^{}$ & 0.004$^{***}$ & 0.001$^{}$ \\
  & (0.001) & (0.001) & (0.001) \\
  & & & \\
\hline \\[-1.8ex]
 Observations & 156.0 & 156.0 & 156.0 \\
 R${2}$ & 0.375 & 0.453 & 0.717 \\
 Adjusted R${2}$ & 0.371 & 0.45 & 0.716 \\
 Residual Std. Error & 0.014(df = 154.0) & 0.013(df = 154.0) & 0.009(df = 154.0)  \\
 F Statistic & 92.575$^{***}$ (df = 1.0; 154.0) & 127.778$^{***}$ (df = 1.0; 154.0) & 391.008$^{***}$ (df = 1.0; 154.0) \\
\hline
\hline \\[-1.8ex]
\textit{Note:} & \multicolumn{3}{r}{$^{*}$p$<$0.1; $^{**}$p$<$0.05; $^{***}$p$<$0.01} \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Unrelated: note that your `\label{}` placement will never work if you plan on referring to this table. It is not the `table` env that addes the number, it is the `\caption` command, so `\label` should be placed after the `\caption`

Comment: Easy you are specifying 3 columns via `\begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{5pt}}lcc}` but you are using 4 columns (count the number of `&` on each line, it is one less than the number of needed columns)

Comment: Unrelated 2: what is up with all those ``\\[-1.8ex]``? Don't put in a blank line if you don't need it. Additionally have a look at the `booktabs` package for better horizontal lines for tables. They also have much better vertical space around them compared to `\hline` etc.

Comment: you should never have `\\ ` after `\hline` is `stargazer` generating that? If so that should be reported as a bug.

Comment: thank you @daleif for editing my question. Re: your second comment, i still do not understand how to edit  `\begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{5pt}}lcc}` to inset the extra column. How can I easily solve this problem generally? Apologies, but I have no prior latex experience.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle the stargazer port to python is buggy. I thought that the purpose of the package was that I would not have to visit the latex stack exchange boards !

Comment: What is the desired alignment of the added column? left-aligned, centered,...? If you want an additional centered column, go for `\begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{5pt}}lccc}`instead of `\begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{5pt}}lcc}`. (Notice the third `c`. If you want a left aligned column, replace this `c` with `l`.)

Comment: There are several things wrong, although `\\\hline` is perhaps the worst. `[!htbp] ` (shouldn't routinely use `!`) `\label{}` (better to not have label than default blank as this will give errors if done twice, and without a `\caption` it will not work anyway.) `92.575$^{***}` numbers should be in math mode and aligned on the `.` so the `***` doesn't spoil the alignment.

Answer (score 1):

The second table needs an extra column in the definition -- added

The cline was extending from 3-4 column -- changed from 2-4 column

But your table is too wide

You need to change the last 2 rows so that they occupy less space

residual std error 0.014
       new line    df=154

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htbp] \centering
  \label{}
\begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{5pt}}lcc}
\\[-1.8ex]\hline
\hline \\[-1.8ex]
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textit{Dependent variable:}} \
\cr \cline{2-3}
\\[-1.8ex] & (1) & (2) \\
\hline \\[-1.8ex]
 Best Random & 0.392$^{***}$ & \\
  & (0.041) & \\
  & & \\
 Worst Random & & 0.518$^{***}$ \\
  & & (0.046) \\
  & & \\
 const & 0.002$^{}$ & 0.004$^{***}$ \\
  & (0.001) & (0.001) \\
  & & \\
\hline \\[-1.8ex]
 Observations & 156.0 & 156.0 \\
 R${2}$ & 0.375 & 0.453 \\
 Adjusted R${2}$ & 0.371 & 0.45 \\
 Residual Std. Error & 0.014(df = 154.0) & 0.013(df = 154.0)  \\
 F Statistic & 92.575$^{***}$ (df = 1.0; 154.0) & 127.778$^{***}$ (df = 1.0; 154.0) \\
\hline
\hline \\[-1.8ex]
\textit{Note:} & \multicolumn{2}{r}{$^{*}$p$<$0.1; $^{**}$p$<$0.05; $^{***}$p$<$0.01} \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\begin{table}[!htbp] \centering
    \label{}
    \begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{5pt}}lccl}%<---------added l column
        \\[-1.8ex]\hline
        \hline \\[-1.8ex]
        & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textit{Dependent variable:}} \
        \cr \cline{2-4}%<---------------------------------added cline 2-4
        \\[-1.8ex] & (1) & (2) & (3) \\
        \hline \\[-1.8ex]
        Best Random & 0.392$^{***}$ & & \\
        & (0.041) & & \\
        & & & \\
        Mean Randoms & & & 0.856$^{***}$ \\
        & & & (0.043) \\
        & & & \\
        Worst Random & & 0.518$^{***}$ & \\
        & & (0.046) & \\
        & & & \\
        const & 0.002$^{}$ & 0.004$^{***}$ & 0.001$^{}$ \\
        & (0.001) & (0.001) & (0.001) \\
        & & & \\
        \hline \\[-1.8ex]
        Observations & 156.0 & 156.0 & 156.0 \\
        R${2}$ & 0.375 & 0.453 & 0.717 \\
        Adjusted R${2}$ & 0.371 & 0.45 & 0.716 \\
        Residual Std. Error & 0.014(df = 154.0) & 0.013(df = 154.0) & 0.009(df = 154.0)  \\
        F Statistic & 92.575$^{***}$ (df = 1.0; 154.0) & 127.778$^{***}$ (df = 1.0; 154.0) & 391.008$^{***}$ (df = 1.0; 154.0) \\
        \hline
        \hline \\[-1.8ex]
        \textit{Note:} & \multicolumn{3}{r}{$^{*}$p$<$0.1; $^{**}$p$<$0.05; $^{***}$p$<$0.01} \\
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end {document}
```

**EDIT for second table fitment --change last 2 rows**

```
\begin{table}[!htbp] \centering
    \label{}
    \begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{5pt}}lccl}
        \\[-1.8ex]\hline
        \hline \\[-1.8ex]
        & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textit{Dependent variable:}} \
        \cr \cline{2-4}
        \\[-1.8ex] & (1) & (2) & (3) \\
        \hline \\[-1.8ex]
        Best Random & 0.392$^{***}$ & & \\
        & (0.041) & & \\
        & & & \\
        Mean Randoms & & & 0.856$^{***}$ \\
        & & & (0.043) \\
        & & & \\
        Worst Random & & 0.518$^{***}$ & \\
        & & (0.046) & \\
        & & & \\
        const & 0.002$^{}$ & 0.004$^{***}$ & 0.001$^{}$ \\
        & (0.001) & (0.001) & (0.001) \\
        & & & \\
        \hline \\[-1.8ex]
        Observations & 156.0 & 156.0 & 156.0 \\
        R${2}$ & 0.375 & 0.453 & 0.717 \\
        Adjusted R${2}$ & 0.371 & 0.45 & 0.716 \\
        Residual Std. Error & 0.014 & 0.013 & 0.009  \\
        &(df = 154.0)&(df = 154.0)&(df = 154.0)\\
        F Statistic & 92.575$^{***}$ & 127.778$^{***}$ & 391.008$^{***}$\\
        & (df = 1.0; 154.0)& (df = 1.0; 154.0)& (df = 1.0; 154.0)\\
        \hline
        \hline \\[-1.8ex]
        \textit{Note:} & \multicolumn{3}{r}{$^{*}$p$<$0.1; $^{**}$p$<$0.05; $^{***}$p$<$0.01} \\
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

[image]

**One more EDIT for alignment of asterisk with digits**

```
\begin{table}[!htbp] \centering
    \label{}
    \begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{5pt}}lccl}
        \\[-1.8ex]\hline
        \hline \\[-1.8ex]
        & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textit{Dependent variable:}} \
        \cr \cline{2-4}
        \\[-1.8ex] & (1) & (2) & (3) \\
        \hline \\[-1.8ex]
        Best Random & 0.392$^{***}$ & & \\
        & (0.041)\phantom{$^{***}$} & & \\
        & & & \\
        Mean Randoms & & & 0.856$^{***}$ \\
        & & & (0.043)\phantom{$^{***}$} \\
        & & & \\
        Worst Random & & 0.518$^{***}$ & \\
        & & (0.046)\phantom{$^{***}$} & \\
        & & & \\
        const & 0.002$^{}$ & 0.004$^{***}$ & 0.001$^{}$ \\
        & (0.001) & (0.001)\phantom{$^{***}$} & (0.001) \\
        & & & \\
        \hline \\[-1.8ex]
        Observations & 156.0 & 156.0 & 156.0 \\
        R${2}$ & 0.375 & 0.453 & 0.717 \\
        Adjusted R${2}$ & 0.371 & 0.45 & 0.716 \\
        Residual Std. Error & 0.014 & 0.013 & 0.009  \\
        &(df = 154.0)&(df = 154.0)&(df = 154.0)\\
        F Statistic & 92.575$^{***}$ & 127.778$^{***}$ & 391.008$^{***}$\\
        & (df = 1.0; 154.0)& (df = 1.0; 154.0)& (df = 1.0; 154.0)\\
        \hline
        \hline \\[-1.8ex]
        \textit{Note:} & \multicolumn{3}{r}{$^{*}$p$<$0.1; $^{**}$p$<$0.05; $^{***}$p$<$0.01} \\
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

[image]

**EDIT**

A little prettyfying never hurts

```
\begin{table}[!htbp] \centering
    \label{}
    \begin{tabular}{lccc}
        \\[-1.8ex]\hline
        \hline \\[-1.8ex]
        & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textit{Dependent variable:}} \
        \cr \cline{2-4}
        \\[-1.8ex] & (1) & (2) & (3) \\
        \hline \\[-1.8ex]
        Best Random & 0.392$^{***}$ & & \\
        & (0.041)\phantom{$^{***}$} & & \\
        & & & \\
        Mean Randoms & & & 0.856$^{***}$ \\
        & & & (0.043)\phantom{$^{***}$} \\
        & & & \\
        Worst Random & & 0.518$^{***}$ & \\
        & & (0.046)\phantom{$^{***}$} & \\
        & & & \\
        const & 0.002$^{}$ & 0.004$^{***}$ & 0.001$^{}$ \\
        & (0.001) & (0.001)\phantom{$^{***}$} & (0.001) \\
        & & & \\
        \hline \\[-1.8ex]
        Observations & 156.0 & 156.0 & 156.0 \\
        R${2}$ & 0.375 & 0.453 & 0.717 \\
        Adjusted R${2}$ & 0.371 & 0.45 & 0.716 \\ \rowcolor{black!20}
        Residual Std. Error & 0.014 & 0.013 & 0.009  \\ \rowcolor{black!20}
        &(df = 154.0)&(df = 154.0)&(df = 154.0)\\          \rowcolor{green!20}
        F Statistic & 92.575$^{***}$ & 127.778$^{***}$ & 391.008$^{***}$\\ \rowcolor{green!20}
        & (df = 1.0; 154.0)& (df = 1.0; 154.0)& (df = 1.0; 154.0)\\
        \hline
        \hline \\[-1.8ex]
        \textit{Note:} & \multicolumn{3}{l}{{\color{black!90}$^{*}$p$<$0.1};{\color{red!80} $^{**}$p$<$0.05};{\color{blue!80!red} $^{***}$p$<$0.01}} \\
    \end{tabular}
```

[image]

Comment: Could you please elaborate a bit more on "residual std error 0.014 new line df=154"?

Comment: please see edit

Answer (score 1):

You can get a much better table with `siunitx` and `booktabs`.

The numeric columns are declared with `S` (see the manual of `siunitx`). Cells that don't contain numbers to be aligned at the decimal point should have their contents braced.

I have added a couple of *ad hoc* commands for the table; in order to keep the width short, the “df” parts are set below the number.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx,booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htbp]
\centering
\sisetup{
  input-open-uncertainty={},
  input-close-uncertainty={},
}
\newcommand{\tn}[1]{\makebox[0pt][l]{$^{#1}$}}
\newcommand{\splitcell}[1]{\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}}#1\end{tabular}}

\caption{Some caption}\label{a-label}

\begin{tabular}{
  @{}
  l
  S[table-format=1.3,table-space-text-pre={(},table-space-text-post={)}]
  S[table-format=1.3,table-space-text-pre={(},table-space-text-post={)}]
  S[table-format=1.3,table-space-text-pre={(},table-space-text-post={)}]
  @{}
}
\toprule
& \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textit{Dependent variable:}} \\
\cmidrule(l){2-4}
& {(1)} & {(2)} & {(3)} \\
\midrule
Best Random  &  0.392\tn{***} &                & \\
             & (0.041)        &                & \\
\addlinespace
Mean Randoms &                &                &  0.856\tn{***} \\
             &                &                & (0.043) \\
\addlinespace
Worst Random &                &  0.518\tn{***} & \\
             &                & (0.046)        & \\
\addlinespace
const        &  0.002         &  0.004\tn{***} &  0.001 \\
             & (0.001)        & (0.001)        & (0.001) \\
\midrule
Observations        & {156}   & {156}   & {156} \\
\addlinespace
R$_{2}$             & {0.375} & {0.453} & {0.717} \\
\addlinespace
Adjusted R$_{2}$    & {0.371} & {0.45}  & {0.716} \\
\addlinespace
Residual Std. Error & {\splitcell{0.014 \\ (df = 154.0)}}
                    & {\splitcell{0.013 \\ (df = 154.0)}}
                    & {\splitcell{0.009 \\ (df = 154.0)}}  \\
\addlinespace
F Statistic & {\splitcell{92.575\tn{***} \\ (df = 1.0; 154.0)}}
            & {\splitcell{127.778\tn{***} \\ (df = 1.0; 154.0)}}
            & {\splitcell{391.008\tn{***} \\ (df = 1.0; 154.0)}} \\
\midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
\multicolumn{4}{@{}l@{}}{\textit{Note:} $^{*}$~$p<0.1$; $^{**}$~$p<0.05$; $^{***}$~$p<0.01$}
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]